# Assign radio button's label instead of value

Tags: javascript, radio-button, label

Consider the following radio buttons in html:

```
<tr>  
    <td> Lighting </td>
    <td> <label for="lighting1"> Off </label> 
        <input id = "lighting1" name="lighting" type="radio" value="0"> </td>
    <td> <label for="lighting2"> Low </label> 
        <input id = "lighting2" name="lighting" type="radio" value="1"> </td>
    <td> <label for="lighting3"> High </label> 
        <input id = "lighting3" name="lighting" type="radio" value="2"> </td>
</tr>
```

I need a javascript statement that will assign the radio button's label on a variable instead of its value, ie 'Off', 'Low' or 'High' instead of '0', '1' or '2'. when the radio button is checked.

It seems so simple and straightforward yet I fail to achieve it no matter what I try. I haven't found any working answers on the forum either. Please spare me of stating all non workable trials and enlighten me with just a single line of code that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch radios using common name and update values using `input.value = newValue`

```js
function updateValues(){
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="lighting"]');
  for(var i = 0; i< radios.length; i++){
    var id = radios[i].getAttribute('id');
    radios[i].value = document.querySelector('label[for="'+id+'"]').textContent.trim()
  }
}

function registerEvents(){
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="lighting"]');
  for(var i = 0; i< radios.length; i++)
    radios[i].addEventListener("change", handleChange)
}

function handleChange(){
  console.log(this.value)
}

registerEvents();
```

```html
<tr>
  <td> Lighting </td>
  <td> <label for="lighting1"> Off </label>
    <input id="lighting1" name="lighting" type="radio" value="0"> </td>
  <td> <label for="lighting2"> Low </label>
    <input id="lighting2" name="lighting" type="radio" value="1"> </td>
  <td> <label for="lighting3"> High </label>
    <input id="lighting3" name="lighting" type="radio" value="2"> </td>
</tr>

<p id="selectedValues"></p>

<button onclick="updateValues()" >Update Values</button>
```

Comment: This is a fine answer but assumes that  'Off', 'Low' and 'High' are known: var values = ["Off", "Low", "High"]; What I'm actually trying to do is read them out of the html page.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh.

Answer (score 0):

```
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
for(var i = 0; i< radioButtons.length; i++)
{
    radioButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        var radioButton = e.target || e.srcElement;
        var label = document.querySelector("label[for='" + radioButton.id + "'");
        alert(label.innerText.trim());
    });
}
```

EDIT: Removed the jquery snippet that I initially added. As the user is looking only for a javascript solution, retaining that alone.

Comment: In javascript? I'm not familiar with jQuery, and the whole thing is done in javascript.

Comment: @MichaelP: I have removed the jquery snippet and edited the answer to contain javascript snippet alone.

Comment: Thanks for the effort